# Apply names to multiple objects

Tags: r

I have a vector with names (only one) and I'd like to apply it to multiple objects, but the function names accepts only one argument (one object), so I have to repeat the process for all the objects I want to name.

```
names(object_1) <- namesvector
names(object_2) <- namesvector
names(object_3) <- namesvector
```

Is it possible to do that in only one step?

Thanks!

Comment: What is the class of your objects `object_1`, `object_2`... ?

Comment: mostly numeric vectors, but I also have a list.

Comment: they all have the same length, of course.

Answer (score 6):

A slightly more compact solution

```
lapply(list(obj_1, obj_2, obj_3), setNames, name_vector)
```

Comment: that's an elegant solution, but it does not really apply the names to the vectors, but it creates a list with named vectors. If you type 'obj_1', for example, you see the obj_1 without names.

Answer (score 1):

You could try putting all your numeric vectors into a list, then `lapply` over them with an assignment.  Something like:

```
# makes some vectors
obj_1 <- 1:10
obj_2 <- 1:10
obj_3 <- 1:10
name_vector <- LETTERS[1:10]

# now apply the names
lapply(list(obj_1,obj_2,obj_3), function(x) {names(x) <- name_vector; x})
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way just for fun:

```
lapply(list(object_1, object_2, object_3), structure, .Names = namesvector)
```

---

All these answers are condemning your objects to a list. If you still want your objects freely accessible (i.e. in the global environment) here's another solution:

---

Sample objects:

```
object_1 <- runif(3)
object_2 <- runif(3)
object_3 <- runif(3)
```

Names you want to apply:

```
namesvector <- letters[1:3]
```

---

Some hackery to apply names:

```
# Objects you want to combine.
items_n <- c("object_1", "object_2", "object_3")

# Make into a list with names of objects needed for promoting to global environment.
items <- structure(lapply(items_n, get), .Names = items_n)

# Add names to object elements.
named <- lapply(items, structure, .Names = namesvector)

# Promote to global environment.
list2env(named, .GlobalEnv)
```

Now you can still reference e.g.:

```
object_1
```

and get its contents back. You could create `items_n` (the list of objects to combine) dynamically as well if you have lots of objects (assuming they have a similar name):

```
items_n <- sapply(1:3, function(x) paste0("object_", x))
```